# Qmysql driver not loaded but it's available

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, ubuntu, qt5

I want to connect my database(mysql) with Qt library on ubuntu 16.04.
But i faced this error:

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

Result of `ldd /Qt-PATH/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so` is:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff9d55a000)
    libmysqlclient_r.so.16 => not found
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007efc887eb000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007efc885b3000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007efc8839a000)
    libssl.so.10 => not found
    libcrypto.so.10 => not found
    libQt5Sql.so.5 => /home/hassan-setayesh/ProgramFiles/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libQt5Sql.so.5 (0x00007efc88154000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /home/hassan-setayesh/ProgramFiles/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007efc87a38000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007efc8781b000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007efc87499000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007efc8718f000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007efc86f79000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007efc86bb0000)
    libicui18n.so.56 => /home/hassan-setayesh/ProgramFiles/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libicui18n.so.56 (0x00007efc86715000)
    libicuuc.so.56 => /home/hassan-setayesh/ProgramFiles/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libicuuc.so.56 (0x00007efc8635d000)
    libicudata.so.56 => /home/hassan-setayesh/ProgramFiles/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers/./../../lib/libicudata.so.56 (0x00007efc8497a000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007efc84775000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0x00007efc84573000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007efc8436b000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007efc84059000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000564692881000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007efc83de9000)
```

And for solving this : `libmysqlclient_r.so.16 => not found`
I link it to `libmysqlclient.so.20.3.2` with these command:
`cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`
`sudo ln -s libmysqlclient.so.20.3.2 libmysqlclient_r.so.16`

My Qt version is 5.7 offline mode.

what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Repeat 10 times:

1. I will never use a symlink to solve a missing library problem due to a different soname
2. I will never use a symlink to solve a missing library problem due to a different soname
3. I will never use a symlink to solve a missing library problem due to a different soname
4. I will never use a symlink to solve a missing library problem due to a different soname
5. I will never use a symlink to solve a missing library problem due to a different soname
6. I will never use a symlink to solve a missing library problem due to a different soname
7. I will never use a symlink to solve a missing library problem due to a different soname
8. I will never use a symlink to solve a missing library problem due to a different soname
9. I will never use a symlink to solve a missing library problem due to a different soname
10. I will never use a symlink to solve a missing library problem due to a different soname

**Never *ever* solve that kind of problems via symlinking**. If your system does not provide the exact soname required by a library or an executable, you'll need to recompile that library or executable. There is a reason why libraries have the soname version number in their file names, and a mismatching soname will result in a `not found` for the dynamic linker/loader. You're just breaking that process *and your entire system* by inserting a broken soname for a library.

## So, **first thing to do: get rid of the symlink you introduced.** Go in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` and remove it. Do it **now**.

---

**Then, how to recompile the plugin so that it works on Ubuntu?**

(Or, actually, anywhere. Even Windows or Mac. Just adapt the instructions)

Step by step:

1. Install the mysql development packages. On Ubuntu it should be the `libmysqlclient-dev` package, but double check in case the name changed on your particular Ubuntu edition. Go on https://packages.ubuntu.com and use the file-based search to look for `mysql.h`.
2. Run the maintanance tool from the installer, and ask it to also install the Qt source components. You'll find the tool in your Qt installation directory.
3. Go under `INSTALL_DIR/Src/5.7/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/mysql` (adjust `INSTALL_DIR` and `5.7` to your actual case).
4. Run **the right** `qmake`. The right one is the one coming from the same installation of Qt, and whose version matches the sources. In your case it's likely to be in `INSTALL_DIR/5.7/gcc_64/bin/qmake`.
5. Run `make`. If it fails to compile due to some library not found, install the required packages on your system. The Ubuntu package search linked above may be useful.
6. Once `make` runs successfully, it will create a brand new  `libqsqlmysql.so`. It should automatically overwrite the one in `INSTALL_DIR/5.7/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers`. If for any reason it's not automatically overwritten, move it manually there.

Done! Enjoy your MySQL database connection.