# Qt Mysql build Driver in ubuntu

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, ubuntu, qt5

I am facing an issue with Mysql Qt :


I have set up my Mysql database server with sample database schema and a table to test out.

code:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <QtSql>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    db.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
    db.setDatabaseName("testQtDB");
    db.setUserName("root");
    db.setPassword("password");
    if(!db.open())
    {
        std::cout<<"data base not opened"<<std::endl;
    }
    else{
        QSqlQuery query("SELECT * From emp");
        std::cout<<"data table row size "<<query.size()<<std::endl;
        for(int i=0;i<query.size();i++)
        {
            std::string data = QString(query.value(i).toString()).toStdString();
            std::cout<<"data table row values "<<data<<std::endl;
        }
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

when I build there is know error but when run the application it says

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QMYSQL QMYSQL3 QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

to over come this issue I have installed libqt5sql5-mysql and libmysqlclient_r but still it remains same

I am current running this program on:

> Ubuntu 14.04
>   Qt 5.7

do I need to set the path of the mysql lib dir like we do in java for mysql connector.

Kindly help me with this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: does we need to set any build Environment for the project properties....!!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40328372/qmysql-driver-not-loaded-but-its-available and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37369480/qsqldatabase-qmysql-driver-not-loaded-on-ubuntu-15-04-64bits

Comment: Thanks for the answer i solved the problem @peppe